# Creating new admin users in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application, I have `Users` who can log in and register and `Admins` who can log in but cannot register themselves for security reasons.

I am leveraging Laravels built in `Auth` functionality so that I can handle logging in and password resets, just with an added provider and guard for `App\Admin`

I am trying to create new Admins with a form that only other Admin users can reach, but am really struggling to get the flow working:

**Here is the method in my `AdminController`**

```
public function store(StoreAdmin $request)
{
    $admin = new Admin();

    $admin->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
    $admin->last_name = $request->input('last_name');
    $admin->email = $request->input('email');
    $admin->password = bcrypt(str_random(60));
    $admin->access_level = $request->input('access_level');

    $admin->save();

    Mail::send(new AdminWelcome($admin));

    return redirect()->route('admin.index');
}
```

This adds a new Admin given the credentials passed through the `$request` variable and also gives them a random password to start off with. It also triggers an email to be sent to the email of the newly created user.

**Here is the `Mail` class I'm using to pass data to the email:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Admin;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Password;

class AdminWelcome extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Undocumented variable
     *
     * @var [type]
     */
    public $admin;

    /**
     * Undocumented variable
     *
     * @var [type]
     */
    public $token;

    /**
     * @param \App\Models\Admin $user
     */
    public function __construct(Admin $admin)
    {
        $this->admin = $admin;

        $this->token = Password::getRepository()->create($admin);
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->to($this->admin->email)
            ->subject('Welcome to ' . config('app.name'))
            ->view('emails.admin.welcome');
    }
}
```

This correctly grabs the newly created admin user as I successfully retrieve this user's name in my email tests. However, the `Password::getRepository()->create($admin);` is not actually generating a token.

Here is the view associated with the email:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<h1>Welcome to <a href="{{ config('app.url') }}">{{ config('app.name') }}</a></h1>
<p>
    Dear {{ $admin->first_name }},
</p>
<p>
    Your account has been approved. You can now pick a password at our site and login.
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                <a href="password/reset" . {{ $token }} class="btn-primary">
                    Pick a password
                </a>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p><em>This link is valid until {{
        Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(config('auth.passwords.users.expire'))->format('Y/m/d') }}.</em></p>
@endsection
```

The token is not added to the URL, neither is it added to the `password_resets` table. Am I forgetting something obvious here?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Version 5.7, would that make any difference?